# file_get_contents on remote .js file returns garbage

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to load the amazon.com [send-to-kindle](https://d1xnn692s7u6t6.cloudfront.net/widget.js) javascript and write it into my compiled javascript package using this code:

```
/* LOAD, INSERT AND MINIFY THE REMOTE KINDLE SCRIPT */
if(false===file_get_contents('https://d1xnn692s7u6t6.cloudfront.net/widget.js'))
{
    $mergeScriptKindle=file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH.'/js/sendtokindle.js');
}
else
{
    $mergeScriptKindle=file_get_contents('https://d1xnn692s7u6t6.cloudfront.net/widget.js');
}

echo $mergeScriptKindle;die;
```

However, when I echo the contents of the file, it returns gibberish:

> ‹½[ÿWÛ8ÿ¿Bøö]íb
>   ¥ÛKÚò€²[îJÛ+ìvï’´O¶”ÄàØ9Ûf÷·ßŒ¾Ø²c‡°ÛwûöÛ¤ÑÌg¾Hé<Þ
>   ÇÉl‘†ãINìÀ!{;»OÈá”þžÄ^L]r9Œ""h2’òŒ§×œy;æ'Yž†Aþ¨wMSòÃ9ÙEò0f'/kïµ÷.¹‡äÆ«wû6‹h>JÒéir ç“$­·Ë¯@pç’1yJ#ÍÉòÂ8ËéŒÎxúEò)¹Ð~Ê£%Ó0H”ÍK.<ÎÓÅvåù‹(Œ9œx£Å:÷£0›pÖ…iOyÞÍùÐÒœáëì‡9ŸÎÒdö_1
>   \Qeµöbšæ8u"îƒn•KJf<§t6©
>   ûð4_ˆnÉ¸Û"ç:Mó0&Æl6Œé¬ìSÐ}Aéàì`z!ÿUéæ;úÎ%ABÐø›ƒÜ»ˆ•
>   ¢9ãâyFÇaLs¡Ë¸Yˆw¨¿]tãyO¦iyÖÝ÷8Ì»£y`?›:äÛÑvD;¹†‘Þ†YŽê×Òb[SžeÀX7‚)B—lî:¥¥Ò<§ÁD°²­$^“‰Óƒ9†#=[B@+mÄ
>   ÌàoßÒZ©Õžfåþƒé[[š'!´ÏúÁpHþúWb!*Åc‹¼|ù’ä‹OFf³í«ç—ú«#xÜ‰×‚öíó,O¦ÐËï J9oµ¿8_µ½bêÅîZÃ^±j_¬Á7×à›kh›¸¯&Þ87©hŠê¥¦7—dõÿ’99LSºJöïÅ'TÅ
>   R~ñ©@‹,HÃYn)m j[9ÿšw®}Õ\´ÂWh}ô“B:ÀÖ#0§tq‘>‚µÁ´l_|té
>   ÆŽÍTè×9®ÑŸÄŒhöø~ÏPoi–×‡{NIßOcÆ¿êÅ9ì[ÕûŽªiÂÈ¹˜ðX7·¯'¡V3IíÃ,8²ÏB¦ù»%WP[Ç)Æ;‰2þæ–Uô!Žêâz¤àOoµŸ°…šJx< #j£Læ›C`Y¥4á(ÅPÂïèei@ZLÏˆÙ@]­ÎxÖÉ€,O®YGF†ÛÂ¯Z‚W¾€Þ,Ì
>   z\
>   ÆIŒ¨½jE-NN0à¥üÀ'"BÏ+Kbµ®ìhq;•½ƒµÚÝCa[rr<½qs:–ô¥••¨ÁÀßPíoèèØŸo™cò·ÙíN0CdC/Ð‘~@|YÛV¤V?=}mãž!iQ\µÑ´ŒÇ"}P@½/…8(JJno5HsŒA„Œa3“ÙˆÓèX¸[á?jßl”ìÍ}_ä›;ZL‚»—Ó“Dh›’lo“Âz{Zf’|4)Š•ºÎ=0
>   åq¯ø"ÃQlóý%©/Yy½ÍÂUCC úù$MnHÌoÈ
>   éIšÂ2,“!:qÎ„Pïmh–€A˜b0¼*]Qa&¡åXK‘Â„fïoâ*8Vñ°*Â¼Ù<›@:i”ò|žÆ„¡¨ÄðaØ-…XÚÚL­R*âPâl®âÜ#Oô  3_RÔ£We¨ƒYžB„òI˜!*Ø¯ªrt†‹ERWüa(HP>—¢“ÒzNÿ(^›÷¬F0eY˜dÙfgÉl>³€Â¾7æ;
>   Ö>ˆô zÜÛCB@ë‹Ñø
>   ãì(   „‰#‹]ÌqîÓ_vÜ”gáïl]¶Aˆ‘D´f²òé|®žó$‰Š~°Ž|‚û?î»Ž•ñ¶·ïF|”ëÉÚJ`À—óØ£×4Œ>aWÒ‡¾MöžÿèícüdûÙª^oÄºÛ³=è†€Õ†)bÃ¼Y’åg2³ÿ~þþ'S‡p´°¿¡®w­”ÿg0®sË5vc
>   ù_'i;wmîÐÐñ\ûƒÐ¥
>   ÅPTm–(»Ð  ¡uxtüúä§ŸßœþýoÏÞ½ÿðÏç¿üúé·ý›úã£ñ$¼¼Š¦q2ûOšåóë›¯‹ß-™DžÑ|â¢Lrw[ñ.§`;¸»û½Åý¾A^¡„ž¾²_§’¼mÁôvv÷ž<Ýöãó¿m±zl{»gX6R¬É·4ñˆ0
>   ¢^vêG‹SŒ<(¥(TX/yI€ÂNY§ú¡*?î%àVÃ¸€;-k¡7"ß¬è(dÕ¡l!ÓD_†ê­9`”Œmë<ÇÊä4·§TÆÑð?*¼Òwm§Þ$å#Ð‘ûK=-Êr.dÓFÙ
>   Í»¨5áKQÿ±†Ú)ØË^³âgíÖl¾O‡Î2—ÀL«òta¼ØY:Šo48ËsKç<‚ÁaëW`ï8ç»@$¯Ü©ŒÖ.í3žS’©qÈ„³.iPcÌrH¾)W³2¼]…5þ:Hà
>   ƒk$ÁÛ1DÎ4ÄºT%‡nÏX‚Uáh‹œ­p:¶ŒØDø±ù‘O¾Îì%½ƒ5`aÒy³*:Åš+¿ƒ¼âà¸ù‚@\H@c³l,Ö¸fàƒÐ6€`êYmòZª¥¬Cu°º
>   \ºO±>—¬ªÉD(Ô±ö¬G™ù±LyD8¦äé¡¼Áh    ¨ŠêŸ¬ã›!^‹ºmÛVÊÓ–¨¡tìÛÓ»Á'ø³ëî•JuêœfËq‘Óø^Á¯Œƒ–hu‰©m$§¿3ø)¢êZ¼ßŽ«@h=
>   š€Ì“*Œ9Éºhû|è à=èdW§¢A”¡Ÿ;ÌGüyI+–ûE-]Ž¤³iù‚å
>   cóCZ\`‘^‘ã2°ILß[&ûÃˆ*W-ƒ9EÈî.®Þ)‰ðÛR'±¤q°R†V§Ó˜ƒ‚V8…ˆÍC¬»Zª]IOšÃØ5¦²½+f@æ7ƒÂ:Üz¥RìªT]ŒÝW‹YÅŸãiˆícøºQ
>   ¢ÚäOÂ!ªëÂ1ú¦chÌBˆè²Mò6Áúà
>   }#^‹@iª„}g;b«ÑŽ«<ºðŽ.Ôº}ê:†ÒVÄë5ál4]VMGŽ»~†Ð8¢Âqâ²t'J.ñ(aqIßÕ2n—˜wÀ|A§†ÕWcÐNšQï¾
>   ¶/íÝªCY^W­õ~K¥•³Ô5Í­F,›²lß³ÃšÎeBÔRX#|ÔÁÙjbá0¶n­cXVkW«ÅˆzÃzÕçÏÔèÃjÅP#
>   “µo÷Þ#.%Â²'ÍBÆ]:gaâJÌw°—ñÈåSŸ3w”$
>   bk¿®8÷—ÿBØíN8eÐ$¯¸a<›çðo&Ž{\Ì¯Ý˜^»q";Àƒ¼NâÊSAW½Iëu³džÜw\¬,S÷¦—¸žyî*œÇKBn'³xÊ)ŸE4àÜ¹¥„J~Ýtb
>   v‡9»q^ÈVV‹7h°†Ç¨d=Ì(ð>¬úù
>   @&¯1„ðG°¥‘g-ßòQœG+o9  ®'¨ÅY56`ÓwÂ-ï4—Ñ?Ž
>   ¸¨å¾-¨‡$d~¾ã*«a™  ^È…—±3vœLAû8S,oXÖ[„¹/qb†"â”`žâÆ‰v‰Ÿx¶çŸäñ"ÃÓÌŠ*ŸdgyeÅøFáO±®‹_¬ÝÑO"¦{aô]ŸÇf'Æ˜H'f»£oP6²®P*/ÑÈLHAä
>   u^R²š•¤+Å¼dƒ¶ûšIªJQ5^ÕfÁ°ÖCrÝì°0J¶xº&FÅ‹òH¡ÃxV–°Ld]i#Wé4ßÌj[Ý^OøíìíÈü>ÊÃ]YWgö$©xÖë’Í]‚§<™çmvcÜbW|bqð‡'ã<˜ÐxÌÍKF<ñTå‚üÉQ{
>   Nò»<[/ÑG÷*àÌfIœq,Þ™§÷øÅ
>   {Œ1Mÿó«áãWŽH9ƒå!^n{ù5£˜ÀÁ_e¼JkôÅ…8ècAœtp¼çn©C©µ¢£È±Póš‘÷Ùà|Ø»
>   ˜WÍŸ§Ð¡(ˆŠ<,¤ÈçZR‹Ú^«×ŸR:á›S)8­ŒñT¨lxÔ§¤Þ0©P~óœ§!ÂßdAêêùBÝ(®Ëg¦Y.†7ö’ñÒZ0Ê$ÛªEÞ,ùü)³6øÛ×lÜ¥kjiÜXš¦™L[êž%-bn£òØ«$Í.þ°ñWm¥ÙÊ[‚ožÍŸGMŸÑV$Ÿ>¼Ugõ<*ž•¯ÓŽ“W¯ÈžJÂñt  ¶

Comment: try `http` instead of `https`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content stored on cloudfront is gzip'd. Being that its stored in that format, its not allowing any content negotiation. So you get the content gzip'd whether you like it or not.

PHP provides `gz` functions that should allow you to decompress this.